# Sorting rows in a dataframe in ascending order according to a column, but according to the whole value of the number

Tags: r

I am currently trying to sort my dataframe in ascending order. However, want my rows to be sorted to be e.g. "nv1, nv2, nv3, nv 15" rather than "nv1, nv14, nv15, nv2, nv3".

Is there a way to do that?

when using the arrange function, my output will be

```
nv1_SRRxxxx
nv100_SRRxxxx
nv12_SRRxxxx
nv13_SRRxxxx
nv144_SRRxxxx
nv151_SRRxxxx
nv16_SRRxxxx
nv173_SRRxxxx
```

but i am hoping to get

```
nv1_SRRxxxx
nv12_SRRxxxx
nv13_SRRxxxx
nv16_SRRxxxx
nv100_SRRxxxx
nv141_SRRxxxx
nv151_SRRxxxx
nv173_SRRxxxx
```

where the rows are sorted according to the value of the numbers before the first "_"

Answer (score 0):

Extract number with a regex and `order`.

```
dat[order(with(dat, as.numeric(regmatches(V1, regexpr(r"{\d*(?=_)}", V1, perl=TRUE))))),,drop=FALSE]
#              V1
# 1   nv1_SRRxxxx
# 3  nv12_SRRxxxx
# 4  nv13_SRRxxxx
# 7  nv16_SRRxxxx
# 2 nv100_SRRxxxx
# 5 nv144_SRRxxxx
# 6 nv151_SRRxxxx
# 8 nv173_SRRxxxx
```

Assuming the variable is called `V1`.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("nv1_SRRxxxx", "nv100_SRRxxxx", "nv12_SRRxxxx", 
"nv13_SRRx12xx", "nv144_SRRxxxx", "nv151_SRR1xx", "nv16_SRRxxxx", 
"nv173_SRRxxxx")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c("nv1_SRRxxxx", "nv100_SRRxxxx", "nv12_SRRxxxx", "nv13_SRRxxxx", "nv144_SRRxxxx", "nv151_SRRxxxx", "nv16_SRRxxxx", "nv173_SRRxxxx")

v[sort(as.integer(gsub("nv(\\d+).+", "\\1", v, perl = T)), index.return = T)$ix]

[1] "nv1_SRRxxxx"   "nv12_SRRxxxx"  "nv13_SRRxxxx"  "nv16_SRRxxxx"  "nv100_SRRxxxx" "nv144_SRRxxxx" "nv151_SRRxxxx" "nv173_SRRxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

:)

If I understand you correctly, you want to arrange the dataset by a column according to the number in a string.

What I would do is to extract the *first* number from each string, convert it to a number and then arrange the column.

In tidyverse, you can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe <- tibble(colA = c("nv1_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv100_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv12_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv13_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv144_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv151_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv16_SRRxxxx",
                    "nv173_SRRxxxx"))

dataframe %>% 
    arrange(as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(colA, "^[^\\d].+?(\\d+)", group = 1)))

# or, if you want to use base R for the matching and extraction
dataframe %>% 
    arrange(as.numeric(gsub("^[^\\d].+?(\\d+)", "\\1", colA)))
```

This is a great example for when it is beneficial to learn some regEx ... I am not very good at it.

The expression `^[^\\d].+?(\\d+)` says to capture the first number it encounters, match it as few times as possible. There are probably better regexes than this, `(?:^[^\\d].+?)(\\d+)(?:.*?$)` perhaps, but it works.

Comment: I would use the last form of the regular expression, as it does not capture anything else than the first number in any of the groups. Regular expressions are very powerful, but a bit ... involved. You should perhaps even consider to first split your column by "_" (see `tidyr::separate_wider_delim()` and then use regex as appropriate to separate out the numbers. Your column contains a typical ID-pattern consisting of several conacenated series. One column for each is normally better and gives you easier access downstream.